# Has anyone modified the port number of orderer.example.com in the docker-compose-base.yaml file in fabric1.4 and then started the network?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

Has anyone modified the port number of orderer.example.com in the docker-compose-base.yaml file in fabric1.4 and then started the network?
I changed 7050 to 7066, but it is still 7050 when I start the network. Can someone help explain the reason and how to solve it?

```
orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    volumes:
        - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7066:7066
```

An error occurred while executing the command

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7066 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

The error is:

```
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7066: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp *.*.*.*:7066: connect: connection refused"
```

Comment: Is it because the port number of the container should not be modified here?

Answer (score 0):

you need set env `ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT`in your `peer-base.yaml` file which locate in `fabric-samples/first-network/base` directory(it is my path,but I think your yaml path should same as me),like this

```
  orderer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7066
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
....some env ignore......
```